# I need an efficient way of duplicating an existing activity in Android Studio

Tags: android

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int currentQuestion;
    public String[] questions;
    public String[] answers;
    int score = 0;

    Button answerButton;
    Button questionButton;
    Button homeButton;///NEW ****
    public TextView questionView;
    public TextView answerView;
    public EditText answerText;
    public TextView scoreText;

    public void main() {

        questions = new String[]{"Type Yes", "Type No", "Type And", "Type The"};     /*Array of Hard Coded Questions*/
        answers = new String[]{"Yes", "No", "And", "The",};                 /*Array of Hard Coded Answers to indexed to match the questions*/
        currentQuestion = -1;                              /*This will index the questions to be used*/
        answerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AnswerButton);
        questionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuestionButton);
        homeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HomeButton);
        questionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
        answerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerTextView);
        answerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);
        scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreText);

        ///Check the user inserted answer string against the correct or incorrect  answers.... NEEDS VALIDATION....
        answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer();
            }
        });
        ///Skips to the next questions
        questionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getNextQuestion();
            }
        });
        /// Returns you to the Home screen
        homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, _MainMenu.class)); 
            }
        });
    }

    public void getNextQuestion() {
        //1st question so reset everything
        if(currentQuestion == -1)
        {
            setupQuiz();
        }

        currentQuestion++;

        //Check to see if the end of the questions has been reached
        if(currentQuestion == questions.length)
        {
            endQuiz();
        }
        else
        {
            questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);
            answerText.setText("");
        }
    }

    public void setupQuiz()
    {
        score = 0;
        answerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        questionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        answerText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        answerView.setText("");
        questionButton.setText("Skip Question");
    }

    public void endQuiz()
    {
        currentQuestion = -1;
        answerButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        questionView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        answerText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        questionButton.setText("Try Again");
        scoreText.setText("Final Score: " + score);
    }

    public void checkAnswer() ///validaion goes here and not in getnextquestion
    {
        String answer = answerText.getText().toString();
        boolean result = answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[currentQuestion]);

        //answer is correct
        if(result == true) {
            score += 10; /* ++ will increment the score by 1, +=10 will increment the score by the value added (10)*/
            answerView.setText("Correct!");
        }/*answerView, text view set to print the string in the event of the correct answer*/
        else //answer was wrong
            answerView.setText("Incorrect, The answer was " + answers[currentQuestion]); /*answers[currentQuestion] answers reads the answer to the current question in use */

        scoreText.setText("Current Score = "+score);
        getNextQuestion();
    }

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            main();
            getNextQuestion();
    }
}
```

I am building a simple Quiz game in Android that currently has a main Menu Activity that links you directly to a quiz activity that will ask you an "x amount of questions". Ultimately I want three difficulty levels for the Quiz. There will be 3 buttons on the home screen that will direct the user to an Easy, Medium or Hard version of the Quiz.

As each activity will be exactly the same other than the actual questions being asked. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of duplicating the class a couple of times without having to rebuild the user interface and then copy the code into the separate classes.

I attached an example of my code that works perfectly fine so far. The game is very simple and is a learning exercise for me for than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for something like this is to use a single `activity`.

Every `activity` makes the application a lot heavier and this is why you usually try to create the smallest number of different `activities` as possible.

If your pages are pretty much the same you should consider adding a simple value and doing different stuffs based on the value.

On `button click`, simply add an `int value` to the `intent` opening the questions `activity` (1 = easy, 2 = medium, 3 = hard, or any value you like) with

```
intent.putExtra("lvl", lvl);
```

Now, on `activity start`, call this number retrieving the value from the `intent` with

```
int myLvl = getIntent().getIntExtra("lvl", 0);
```

now simply call a switch:

```
switch(myLvl){
  case 1: doLvl1Stuffs();
          break;
  case 2: doLvl2Stuffs();
          break;
  case 3: doLvl3Stuffs();
          break;
  default: throw new Exception("no lvl found");
          break;
```

Hope this helps, but generally avoid creating more activities than the needed ones

Comment: thank you, im working on this now. looks like a great solution and generally just good practice for the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real answer here is the good old "prefer composition over inheritance" mem.

Example: upon "collection" your UI elements; you could create a helper class like

```
public class QuizButtonManager {
  private final Button answerButton;
  private final Button questionButton;
  private final Button homeButton;

  public QuizButtonManager(Button answerButton ... ) {
    this.answerButton = answerButton;
  ...
```

And then you simply *move* your `setupQuiz()` and `endQuiz` methods into that class.

Then you look into other responsibilities that you have currently forced into your activities. You "cut" them out and put them into distinct classes; thus enabling much simpler "re-use".

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to Create BaseActivity that contains all the Mutual Components and the other activities extend from it and implement their logic

but as you say it's all the same. the difference is the Questions so you don't need to create multiple activities you can use the same activity and set a flag to know what is the current difficulty and set the questions based on it